# Android in-app purchase type

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

I'm developing an app with in-app purchase but there is one aspect that is not clear for me: in the Developer Console which kind of in-app item can I upload? Theoretically can I upload a photo or an mp3 to sell within my app? In that case have I to insert that photo inside an apk or I just have to upload the photo file in the Developer Console in the in-app section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With an in-app purchase the user only gets access to a certain thing, the access is managed by Google, Google will know if the user has made this purchase and you can request that information.

What you do with this information is up to you, you can show a picture you delivered with your apk or you can download a new picture from the internet or whatever you want.

This is totally independent from Google or the Developer Console.